# AJAX auto on views (without clicking submit button)

Tags: views, 8, ajax

I'm working on a view with exposed filters ; I want it to be reloaded when a select list (based on a taxonomy) has its value changed by an user. However, by default, AJAX in Views needs a click on the submit button : "Options such as paging, table sorting, and exposed filters will not initiate a page refresh."

How can we improve that ? Why does Views not offer an option for that, it's not just about perfs considerations ?

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable AJAX in Views, you can also edit "Exposed Form Style" settings. There is a checkbox in there that says "Autosubmit" which will react whenever a user changes an exposed filter.

Edit: sorry, that is for Drupal 7. I see you have listed Drupal 8. For Drupal 8, this was removed and is now being added in an effort in the CTools module. You can see the updates here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2475595

[According to this comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/2475595#comment-12024255), you can apply the latest patch in that thread to CTools 8.x beta1 release, enable "CTools Views" module to add the functionality back in.